# Google gmail quickbutton action

Tags: email, button, action, gmail-api, google-schemas

I'm reading about the new development of Google quick action buttons in the mail inbox.
I'm a little bit lost in this topic and not understand how I can include this function in my emails.
I have read about DKIM/SPF but I don't know if this functionality could need to do an google app.
I have my mail server with marketing segmentation and I want this button is visible when email come to client (destiny) gmail inbox (guess only works in gmail....). If i have included the markup code in html in my emails, why i can't see this button?

would it need create a specific mail application to implement this feature and send emails from this app? Someone tried this?

I know maybe this has been reply before but i think must start more down... so.. sorry.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are ready to launch your marked up emails to your users, you will need to register with Google. Please follow this process:

1.Send a real-life email coming from your production servers (or a server with similar DKIM/SPF/From:/Return-Path: headers) including the markup / schema to schema.whitelisting+sample@gmail.com.

2.If you send a test/blank email, an email that does not contain schema or if you don't send an email for review your application will be silently discarded.

3.Make sure that the markup is correct prior to sending the email. For more details see Testing your Schema. Especially make sure the email passes the Email markup [Tester](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/) and that there are no errors, also make sure to include as much data as possible.

4.Gmail removes all markup when forwarding an email. Do not forward the email but send it directly.

Fill out the registration form available [here](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1PA-vjjk3yJF7MLPOVKbIz3MBfhyma2obS8NIZ0JYx8I/viewform?pli=1).

Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google) for the documentation.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending a **promotional** email (offers, etc.)?

If yes, then you are likely to be delivered to the Promotions tab, where quick actions do not work (according to Litmus - https://litmus.com/ebooks/gmail-ebook/gmail-ebook/).

Quick Actions work best in the Inbox for **transactional** emails.
("Here is your booking confirmation" [Check-in now] quick action)

These typically arrive directly in the Inbox.